# Finding an element with JSoup

Tags: jsoup

Using JSoup I can find all my divs using this:

```
doc.select("div.result[jobstatus='applied']");
```

But these divs could be anywhere in my HTML. Is there a way to tell JSoup to find them no matter where they are? Currently I have to specify some nesting like:

```
doc.select("div > div > div.result[jobstatus='applied']");
```

Comment: Please give us the error that you get when you use the first selector. It looks okay and actually should get *ALL* divs with a class 'result' and a tag named 'jobstatus' and value 'applied'. BTW, I think you can leave out the `'` around `'applied'`: `doc.select("div.result[jobstatus=applied]")`

Comment: It should work. Can you please provide your HTML?

Comment: Also take a look [here](https://github.com/DavidePastore/stackoverflow34047739) (there are tests also).

Answer (score 0):

Idea proposed by [@luksch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229229/luksch):

> Please give us the error that you get when you use the first selector. It looks okay and actually should get ALL divs with a class 'result' and a tag named 'jobstatus' and value 'applied'. BTW, I think you can leave out the `'` around `'applied'`: `doc.select("div.result[jobstatus=applied]")`